# In my custom texture pack where there are no cubes, the ground is invisible

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm creating a round wood texture pack, but I'm having problems because where there's no pixel it's transparent at the bottom, I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve this.

[image]

[image: [][image]